# Facebook Python-SDK VS. PyFacebook?

Tags: python, facebook, pyfacebook

I'm starting to develop a facebook application using Django.

I'm trying to choose the appropriate API wrapper for my application and I can't decide whether to use PyFacebook (very well documented but no official release) or the official Facebook Python SDK (which is surprisingly poorly documented).

Are there any major differences between the two that I'm missing?

Thank you,
Liz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe [PyFacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) was made for the old Facebook API (used to be the way to go) while the [Facebook Platform Python SDK](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/) is a new official library from facebook and is aimed towards the new [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

So I suggest you start using the latter. And yeah the documentation totally sucks in both cases, took me a while to figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

For you latecomers: The most recent up-to-date seems to be: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/

Comment: Hmm...
So maybe this is the reason why PyFacebook wasn't updated in the last few months.  :)

Comment: It's a guess, I'm not sure, It also seems like the new official library is very much a work in progress, but i'd stick to it.

Comment: However, the current (un)official library still uses the older Facebook API, which will be turned off in the future. Until a better solution comes along, you might have the best luck just calling the REST api using requests.